# Django custom forms.clean() method not working

Tags: django, django-forms, error-checking

I've been looking for an answer for a while, but i really don't know how this happens. I'm trying to make a form that receives 2 files, and I'm overriding the clean() method to check if the names and extensions are correct. This is what I have:

```
def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = super(UploadForm, self).clean()
  obs_filename = cleaned_data.get('obs').name.split('.')
  nav_filename = cleaned_data.get('nav').name.split('.')
  if obs_filename[0] != nav_filename[0] or [obs_filename[1], nav_filename[1]] != ['obs', 'nav']:
     raise forms.ValidationError('Filenames do not match.')
  if os.path.isfile(PROJECT_ROOT + '/data/unprocessed/' + '.'.join(obs_filename)) and os.path.isfile(PROJECT_ROOT + '/data/unprocessed/' + '.'.join(nav_filename)):
     raise forms.ValidationError('Files already exist.')
  return cleaned_data
```

The problem is, when I use this, the check for input doesn't work (the form submits without selecting any files). When I remove this code, it works fine.
The call to `super(UploadForm, self).clean()` is the same as in the django documentation for custom clean() functions. I'm using django 1.4. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: The code looks good. Does your clean() method get executed? You can "assert 0" in the first line.

Comment: Just checked, it does execute

Answer (score 2):

File fields are a bit more complicated; you have to make sure your files are bound to your form when you instantiate it. If you use class-based generic views, this should happen automatically, so if you're not seeing them then I'm guessing you're not. In which case, have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files. In short, when you instantiate your form, you have to get the files from `request.FILES` and pass these in as a separate argument to your form e.g. `f = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

Also make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `FORM` tag in the HTML.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you mentioned, but it isn't working. I basically copied that code for uploading files and changed the names of variables. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hmmm, do you see anything in self.cleaned_data? Is it different to cleaned_data? What about self.files?